# Use ArcMap to export geodatabase,data is missing

Tags: arcmap, esri-geodatabase

I am using ArcMap 10.5

After I exported the geodatabase,when I loaded the layer on the android device,I found that the number of spots on the layer decreased.
In order to find out the reason, I checked the data in the geodatabase through sqliteManager and found that the original layer has a total of 75 rows fo data, while the exported geodatabase has only 74 row of data.

It is not a special case.When the other layer is exported,the total data is 1792 rows, but only 1789 rows are actually exported.
What caused this situation?

[image]  [image]

[image]  [image]

Comment: In your first screen capture, the last record has FID of 74, but total records is 75. This sugests that there is an FID which equals zero.......maybe when you export, 0 is considered an invalid ID and as such, that record is left out?

Comment: Thank nr_aus. FID I also thought about it.But in the first screenshot I lost the last row of data,and in the second screenshot I lost the middle.As a database,ID normally start at 0 and increments.

Comment: According to the data I checked, there was a statement that geodatabase would have problems supporting Chinese,because my table contained Chinese content, but I still couldn't determine the reason

Comment: ahhh yes possibly invalid record because of language settings maybe. Not sure about that one. PS: Database ID that are zero can cause problems with systems as they are often treated as NULL or empty value. Best practice is to not use Zero, even though ESRI may do this by default.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to change the FID,reply late